# dask-distributed configuration file for dashboard_address

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Is it possible to specify default port for Dask dashboard in a YAML config file? So that SSH tunneling can be set for a non-random port. I know I can do it like so:

```py
cluster = LocalCluster(dashboard_address='localhost:8899')
```

But can this default be specified in a config file?

I tried

```py
dask.config.set({'distributed.dashboard_address': 'localhost:8899'})
```

but new clusters would still give warning about default port 8787 being occupied (I have RStudio server running on that port) and serve dashboard on a random port.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dask.config.set` will change the value only within the current session, not update the config files. To set values that get seen by all Dask processes, see [this section](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#yaml-files) of the docs. The keys in the YAML file are the same as the argument/keys you are trying to use. Obviously, all machines where you want to set a default must have the config file present in the location Dask expects to look (e.g., `~/.config/dask/*.yaml`)

As that page goes on to describe, you can also use environment variables with special names, if that is easier for you to set up.

Comment: I tried adding `distributed > dashboard > address: "localhost:8899"` and `distributed > dashboard-address: "localhost:8899"` to `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml`. Restarted JLab. New parameters were visible in `dask.config.config`, but new cluster would still try to use port 8787. Either default address is not taken from config, or the parameter path is different.